# Aptana Terminal Set PHP Path

Tags: php, terminal, aptana3

How it is possible to integrate the php.exe to the terminal of Aptana? I can't modify the PATH environment variable on my Windows XP, because i am not admin.
Here what i write in the terminal:

```
$ php /d/Program\ Files/xampp/php/file.php
```

and that is the error message:

```
sh.exe": php: command not found
```

If there is another solution?
THX in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Windows so the menus maybe labeled slighly differently but have a look at the preference pane :

**Preferences** > **Aptana Studio** > **Editors** > **PHP** > **PHP Interpreters**

Comment: I've also done this before, but only the terminal recognizes is not php.exe.